# Asp.net server controls are not changing its text while selecting new culture language

Tags: asp.net, webforms, localization, globalization, resx

I want to implement localisation in web forms. For this I have created resource files under App_GlobalResourses.

At my web forms both html and asp.net server controls exist. I have replaced both text as shown below respectively:

<%= Resources.Resource.Email%> (for html controls)
 and
  asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, Email %>" /> (for asp.net controls)

Now I have a dropdown for switching culture. When I change culture, all html controls text changed according to new culture but asp.net server controls text is not changing.

How can I change asp.net server controls text.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
what I did:
(I believe there are better solutions but I did not find them).
I have an asp:button named btnSubmit. its text comes from "Resources.MyResource.SubmitText".

in document.ready() function I add the follwing line:

```
$("#<%= btnSubmit.ClientId %>").val("<%= Resources.MyResource.SubmitText %>");
```

so when the page is ready the value of my button is changed to the current resource,
and it works perfectly.